# Bash if condition to delete old users from specific date

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I'm writing a bash script to get list of users using rest api and to delete the users who are not active for 6 months. For this, I have extracted the json data and fetched name and date fields. Now Im trying to write an if condition to delete the users who are inactive from June. But condition is not working. Could someone please help??

```
userlist="2022-4-30
date= date -d "-6 month" +%Y-%m-%d
if [[ "$userlist" < "$date" ]]
then
  echo "Inactive user. Delete it"
else
  echo "Don't delete"
fi
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) first and fix the obvious mistakes ..

Comment: The first two lines should have been `userlist=2022-04-30` and `date=$(date -d "-6 month" +%Y-%m-%d)`

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is mismatched, and you are doing a string compare.

If your formatting matched, it would probably work -

```
$: [[ 2022-4-30 < 2022-06-15 ]] && echo older || echo nope 
nope

$: [[ 2022-04-30 < 2022-06-15 ]] && echo older || echo nope
older
```

You don't have  leading zero on your month, and `4` is greater than `0` in any string basic match.

Better to switch to actual math, though. This is too fragile.

Change your formatting to epoch seconds, and use `((...))` instead of `[[ ... ]]` to test it.

```
$: cat ckdt
#!/bin/bash
cutoff=$( date -d "-6 month" +%s )               # get base for compares
for m in 7 6 5 4                                 # generate samples to test
do test_date=$( date -d "-$m month" +%Y-%m-%d )  # get an input date
   printf "%s: " "$test_date"                    # show the generated date
   testval=$( date -d "$test_date" +%s )         # convert to epoch seconds
   if ((testval < cutoff))                       # simple math comparison
   then echo "Inactive user. Delete it"
   else echo "Do not delete"
   fi
done
```

Note that without specifying a time, H:M:S default to 00:00:00, and that `<` is not `<=`, so the sample date from 6 months ago is *exactly* the cutoff timestamp, and not *less than*, so it says to delete it.

```
$: ./ckdt
2022-05-15: Inactive user. Delete it
2022-06-15: Inactive user. Delete it
2022-07-15: Do not delete
2022-08-15: Do not delete
```